# evince Document Viewer displays at double the actual size

Tags: gnome, evince

When I look at a PDF of an A4 paper (or US Letter-sized paper), and set the zoom scale to 100%, the paper on the screen looks twice the actual width (42 cm instead of 21 cm). This happens with all PDF files. On the other hand, if I look at the file at 100% using Adobe Reader on Windows, it displays at the correct size. In both cases, my screen is HD at about 100 dpi. Why is evince wrong? Is there a setting to correct it?

Both my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) and desktop (Ubuntu 21.10) have the same issue.

By comparison, Google Chrome displays the same PDF files correctly.

On my laptop:

```
$ evince --version
GNOME Document Viewer 3.36.10
```

On my desktop:

```
$ evince --version
GNOME Document Viewer 40.4
```

Comment: Is the issue present in alternative document viewers like Atril or Okular?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I don't have either of those viewers, but Google Chrome is another alternative viewer and that works fine, displaying it correctly at 100%. Adding this info to the question now.

Comment: Please check if it is present in atril (`sudo apt install atril`). That will help to decide whether the issue is in the backend (which both atril and evince use), or if it is a evince specific bug.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi atril works correctly at 100% too, so it does indeed look like an evince-specific bug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same issue that was reported to the evince developers 2 years ago:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1335

It has not been fixed yet.